# LEFT outer join returns returns duplicate rows even after adding distinct

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, left-join

Restricting the price change table to select a particular item

```
select * from price
where item = '13'
```

results of the query above

```
item       Date_Changed     New     Old          START_DATE         end_DATE
13  01/11/2018 00:00    5.61    4.88    01/11/2018 00:00    30/11/2018 00:00
13  30/11/2018 00:00    2.84    5.61    01/11/2018 00:00    17/12/2018 00:00
13  17/12/2018 00:00    2.39    2.84    30/11/2018 00:00    17/12/2018 00:00
```

sales table

```
Date    Item    Qty Amount
05/07/2018 00:00    13  3   14.64
05/07/2018 00:00    13  3   14.64
04/07/2018 00:00    13  3   14.64
02/07/2018 00:00    13  1   4.88
02/07/2018 00:00    13  6   29.28
06/07/2018 00:00    13  7   34.16
03/07/2018 00:00    13  4   19.52
12/07/2018 00:00    13  2   9.76
10/08/2018 00:00    13  1   4.88
```

> Sample code

```
SELECT distinct a.[Inv]
  , (CASE 
        WHEN a.Date <=  b.START_DATE  THEN  (b.Old * a.Qty)
        WHEN a.Date between  b.START_DATE  and b.dt_end_DATE  THEN  (b.New * a.Qty)
        ELSE 0
   END) as calc_amount
   ,(a.[amount] - (CASE 
        WHEN a.Date <=  b.START_DATE  THEN  (b.Old * a.Qty)
        WHEN a.Date between  b.START_DATE  and b.end_DATE  THEN  (b.New * a.Qty)
        ELSE 0
   END)) as variance
[sales] a 
left outer join price b
on a.[Item] = b.item 
where b.item = '13'
```

The script then returns 27 rows instead of 9 rows. can someone assist on how i can improve my script to be more accurate

Comment: 3 * 9 = 27. (Poor sample data, it need other id's than 13 too.)

Comment: Could you tell us what you want to do ?  
It's normal that you have 27 row because you have a table with 3 row and an other with 9 rows.
9 * 3 = 27 rows.

Comment: i want to validate the price changes if they were effected correctly, so it will be the price * quantity. Then Amount - (price * quantity)

Comment: hi @jarlh the other unique fields are in the sales table, which are Invoice and Customer_No. But in the price table the only unique value is the item

Comment: when joining the tables you should join based on the date condition so that it could map only one price record with one sale. i.e. it should pick up the pice record relevant to sales date.

Comment: @omah94 why do the query you wrote have a start_date column as it isn't in the provided sample data schema

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) PS You don't say what you want. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make your post self-contained.

Comment: thanks @philipxy will do an edit to the question

Comment: @kirangadhe this was me trying to come up with start and end date , but the original date in price table is the date_changed

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it  and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: @omah94 Your start and end dates are overlapping... Is this on purpose?

Comment: @Shnugo this was do add more detail as required by kirangadhe

Comment: Amusingly your title says "returns returns duplicate rows".

Comment: @philipxy are you here to mark typos.

Comment: I just thought anyone would find it humourous that "returns" was accidentally duplicated immediately before the mention of "duplicates".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `outer apply`.  I assume you want the most recent start date from `price`, so this looks like:

```
select s.*,
       (case when s.date <= p.start_date
             then p.Old * s.Qty
             else p.New * s.Qty
        end) as calc_amount
from sales s outer apply
     (select top (1) p.*
      from prices p
      where p.item = s.item and
            p.start_date <= s.date
      order by p.date desc
     ) p
```

Comment: This worked but however left a few product items. i think i just need to fix how i computed the start and end dates

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for. but perhaps you can skip the join?

I created 2 sample data with the columns that you might need.

```
DECLARE @price table (item varchar(2),date_start date, new_price numeric(9,2))

Insert into @price (item , date_start,new_price) 
values
    ( '13', '20190101', '1.00'),
    ( '13', '20190102', '1.01'),
    ( '13', '20190103', '1.02')


DECLARE @sales table (item varchar(2),date_sales date,qty int)

Insert into @sales (item , date_sales,qty) 
values
    ( '13', '20190101', '5'),
    ( '13', '20190101', '2'),
    ( '13', '20190102', '5'),
    ( '13', '20190102', '2'),
    ( '13', '20190103', '5'),
    ( '13', '20190103', '2')


declare @item as varchar(2) = '13'
SELECT (select top (1) new_price from @price b where a.date_sales>=b.date_start and b.item = @item order by b.date_start desc ) * a.qty as 'new_price* qty'
from @sales a 
where a.item = @item
```

I have not tested this in a table with a huge data set, so I also can't vouch for the speed of this query. I believe it would be better to have some kind of other ID to join the table

Comment: Please don't answer unclear questions, post a comment asking for clarification. Lack of a [mcve] is reason to be closed--to have answers blocked from being posted. This question should be downvoted & close voted, not answered. If you don't' have the reputation then wait. Unfortunately some people guess anyway. That often leads to a mess of confusion, comments & edits.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear... You added sample data, but I doubt this is correct...

Your price table is open to erronous data. It would be better to store just the price and a `validFrom`-date. In this case you can pick the price on a give date easily. Your format is open to overlapping periodes and there is no good reason to store the former price once again. That's why I ignore all fields you should not use...

Try this. I've changed the dates in a way to simulate validity periodes.

A *mock-up* scenario (please to this the next time for us):

```sql
CREATE TABLE priceMock(item INT, Date_Changed DATE, New DECIMAL(10,4), Old DECIMAL(10,4), [START_DATE] DATE, end_DATE DATE);

SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
INSERT INTO priceMock VALUES
 (13,'01/11/2018 00:00',5.61,4.88,'01/07/2018 00:00','06/07/2018 00:00')
,(13,'30/11/2018 00:00',2.84,5.61,'07/07/2018 00:00','10/07/2018 00:00')
,(13,'17/12/2018 00:00',2.39,2.84,'11/07/2018 00:00','15/08/2018 00:00');
GO

CREATE TABLE salesMock ([Date] DATE, Item INT, Qty INT, Amount DECIMAL(10,4));

SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
INSERT INTO salesMock VALUES
 ('05/07/2018 00:00',13,3,14.64)
,('05/07/2018 00:00',13,3,14.64)
,('04/07/2018 00:00',13,3,14.64)
,('02/07/2018 00:00',13,1,4.88 )
,('02/07/2018 00:00',13,6,29.28)
,('06/07/2018 00:00',13,7,34.16)
,('03/07/2018 00:00',13,4,19.52)
,('10/07/2018 00:00',13,2,9.76 )
,('10/08/2018 00:00',13,1,4.88 );
GO
```

I'd add an *inline-table-valued-function* to get exactly one single line back.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetPriceForItemOnDate(@item INT,@ValidOn DATE)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM priceMock
    WHERE item=@item
    AND [START_DATE] <= @ValidOn
    ORDER BY [START_DATE] DESC
GO
```

--This query will combine your sales data with the price valid on the given date

```
SELECT s.[Date]
      ,s.Item
      ,s.Qty
      ,p.New AS CurrentPrice
      ,s.Qty * p.New AS ComputedAmount
FROM salesMock s
OUTER APPLY dbo.GetPriceForItemOnDate(s.item,s.[Date]) p 
GO
```

--Clean up (carefull with real data)

```
DROP FUNCTION dbo.GetPriceForItemOnDate;
DROP TABLE priceMock;
DROP TABLE salesMock;
```

The idea in short:

The function will first filter to price lines for the given item. The second filter will cut the list and return just the prices for the given date and before the given date. As we sort this by the date in descending order we will get the latest price on top. By using `TOP 1` we return just the one single line we want.

General remark: I use a `validFrom`-approach here. But you can turn this to the opposite and use a `validTo`-approach. The idea is the same.